# Selenium FindElement and Chrome in Headless mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

After starting chromedriver.exe in headless mode [following this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607084/selenium-chromedriver-does-not-recognize-newly-compiled-headless-chromium-pytho) and using just these arguments

```
 options.AddArgument("headless");
 options.AddArgument("window-size=1280,960");
```

The chromedriver opens invisibly. But Selenium's `FindElement()` command is not finding anything on the headless Chrome page.  Instead it throws this exception:

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element:

**Q1:** Has anyone had success running Selenium commands in Chrome's headless mode?

**Q2:** Have you been able to use `FindElement` with a chromedriver running in headless mode?  If yes, how did you do it?

---

After reading more, perhaps something along these lines may be necessary? Add this to the Chrome startup options and then maybe connect chromedriver to it?
`"remote-debugging-port=9222"`
But with that option the IWebDriver and chromedriver does not open.

---

**Background info:** to answer, why would you want to do this?  The primary reason was for tests run as a part of CI.  These are tests that run on a VM and may not support 1080p monitors. If we ran it in headless mode and set the resolution that way we could.

Comment: SpecFlow has no FindElements. It has nothing to do with browser automation. This issue is about Selenium.

Comment: I use Selenium + Chrome headless all the time. Don't know how that helps you, as I do not understand what your question is. Perhaps have a read through [ask].

Comment: It seems like this issue comes if there's a proxy involved (like proxymob or similar) while using `Selenium + Chrome + SomeProxy (for diverting calls to end points while running your non-Unit tests like IT/FT/Selenium browser based tests etc) + running tests in HEADLESS mode`. I would say try using a different proxy server (Traefik etc).

Comment: It may be related to this bug: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4477

Answer (score 2):

Add below lines of code in your main class:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.setHeadless(true); 
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false); options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'"); 
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*"); 
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--headless"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```